# Mapstruct Reporting Policy not working on nested properties

Tags: java, nested, mapstruct

I'm using mapstruct in my project for my model mappings. To ensure, that every target property is handled in the mapper, I use the unmappedTargetPolicy = Error.

My problem is, that I have nested classes in my model and I what to ensure, that every property of the nested classes is mapped too.

The following things I have found out:

1. if I map nothing of the nested classes (no propery and not the nested class itself), I get the expected compile Error --> OK
2. if I define an explicit mapping for the nested class, I get the expected compile error for every unmapped property of the nested class --> OK
3. But if i map at least one property of the nested class in the mapping definition of the base class, i get no error --> Not OK for me (e.g. @Mapping(source = "abc", target = "memberOfNestedClassType.abc")

How can I ensurce in my mappings, that every target property is handled even if I don't use explicit mappers for the nested class?

Or maybe this is a bug in mapstruct?

Thanks for your help!

CodeExample (for case 3. NestedMember.b is not mapped):

```
// Target Class
    package test;

public class Target {

    public String x;
    public String y;
    public NestedClass nestedMember;
    
    public static class NestedClass {
        public String a;
        public String b;
    }
}

// Source class
package test;

public class Input {

    public String source;
}

// Mapping
package test;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.ReportingPolicy;

@Mapper(unmappedSourcePolicy = ReportingPolicy.WARN, unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR)
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "x", constant = " ")
    @Mapping(target = "y", constant = " ")
    @Mapping(target = "nestedMember.a", source = "source")
    Target map(Input input);
}
```

// generated Impl

```
package test;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import test.Target.NestedClass;

@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2021-05-18T09:22:27+0200",
    comments = "version: 1.4.2.Final, compiler: Eclipse JDT (IDE) 1.3.1200.v20200916-0645, environment: Java 11.0.10 (AdoptOpenJDK)"
)
public class MyMapperImpl implements MyMapper {

    @Override
    public Target map(Input input) {
        if ( input == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Target target = new Target();

        target.nestedMember = inputToNestedClass( input );

        target.x = " ";
        target.y = " ";

        return target;
    }

    protected NestedClass inputToNestedClass(Input input) {
        if ( input == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        NestedClass nestedClass = new NestedClass();

        nestedClass.a = input.source;

        return nestedClass;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some code?

Comment: Could you share the generated code from the target folder (YourClassImpl)?

Comment: I have added a code example